# Is it possible to correct a mistaken downvoted answer?

Tags: support, down-votes

I realized that I downvoted an answer by mistake in this morning. I mean I did not realize when it happened. I have just realized now when I can see a change in my reputation. It possibly happened when I was accessing stackoverflow from my Ipad. Is it possible to correct this mistake? It seems that I am not able to do that by myself because it happened more than an hour ago.

Comment: If you can see anything that needs improving in the answer then an edit will unlock the votes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to undo your vote, you can either ask the answerer to make an edit so your vote is unlocked, or you can make an edit yourself if you have the privilege to do this. Try not to abuse this though.

If your vote is negligible, for example your 1 downvote against 10 upvotes, I wouldn't worry too much about it. Mistakes happen.